# Iterate inside Python list element

Tags: python

How do I read in a file that has a line of text but I need to iterate inside each element? The file needs to be accessed inside the script beyond the scope of the "with" statement.

For example, file.txt contains the single line "abcdefg" without the quotes.  If I write the code below, it doesn't work as I believe I'm creating a single element inside the list (i.e. lines = ['abcdefg']:

```
file = 'file.txt'
with open(file) as file_object:
    lines = file_object.readlines()
for letter in lines:
     if letter == "a":
         print(letter)
```

I'm assuming this creates a single element of "abcdefg" inside lines which of course won't equal "a".

I can get around this by converting the list to a string:

```
{snip}
text_file_string = ''.join(lines)
for letter in text_file_string:
    if letter == "a":
        print(letter)
```

This does work.  I guess my real question is, is there a better way to accomplish this?  It seems like a roundabout method to make it a list and THEN a string.  I suppose I could just import it directly to a string and skip making it a list all together.  I just would like to know if I could do want I want with it as a list?

Comment: What about using a *nested* `for` loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like what you're looking for is `.read()`, not `.readlines()`. `.readlines` returns an array of lines.  You want the entire file as a string, thus `.read()`.

```
file = 'file.txt'
with open(file) as file_object:
    content = file_object.read()
    for letter in content:
         if letter == "a":
             print(letter)
```

Answer (score 0):

The loop over the lines gives you one line at a time. Loop over a line to get one character at a time:

```
file = 'file.txt'
with open(file) as file_object:
    lines = file_object.readlines()
for line in lines:
    for letter in line:
        if letter == "a":
             print(letter)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to nest a second for loop.

```
file = 'file.txt'
with open(file) as file_object:
    lines = file_object.readlines()
for line in lines:
    for letter in line:
        if letter == "a":
            print(letter)
```

Comment: I didn't even think of nested loops. This works great too as it preserves the data in list form.

Answer (score 0):

Agreeing with everyone else but with one additional suggestion. File objects are iterable. You can make your code simpler by taking advantage of this fact like this.

```
with open("myfile.txt", "rt") as file_ob:
    for line in file_ob:
        for letter in line:
            if letter == "a":
                print(letter)
```

Comment: I'm new to python (less than a couple weeks) so I'll have to google the "rt" argument.  Thanks for that though @Phil Cote.  So many ways to do things it can be overwhelming at times.